# how to use regex with variables instead of string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, variables

Asked a few times, but I can't get it to work.

I'm doing a lot of these all over a script replacing various class names.

```
label.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)ui-icon-checkbox-on(?!\S)/g , ' ui-icon-globe');
```

and wanted to replace my `replace` call with a generic function which is being passed a string like `ui-icon-checkbox-on` and returns a regex object to handle my replace.

However, this is not working = it's not replacing anything:

```
var foo = function (className) {
  return new RegExp("(?:^|\s)" + className + "(?!\S)", "g");
};

label.className = label.className.replace(foo("ui-icon-checkbox-on"), ' ui-icon-globe');
```

And I'm at a loss trying to understand why.

**Question**:
How to correctly create a regex object, and use it to replace a string with another string?

Thanks!

PS: and no, I don't want to use jQuery to do it :-)

Comment: You'd better use [classList](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) property if you are not obliged to support old browers. Property is IE10+.

Comment: old browsers I must support... otherwise you are correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the escaped RegExp sequences:

```
var foo2 = function (className) {
  return new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?!\\S)", "g");
  //----------------------^^^---------------------^^^
};
```

Your original function would return:

```
foo("ASD")
// returns:
/(?:^|s)ASD(?!S)/g
```

but we're after this:

```
foo2("ASD")
// returns:
/(?:^|\s)ASD(?!\S)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
var rx = /[W].*/;
var text = "Hello World"
text.replace( rx, "$1" );
```